Upload image in input field according to user condition
Actually, my code works on 1 button and two input fields(text). user click on add field button, two input fields(text) shown. one is use as a key and second input field use as value of that key. Now, I want when user type 'logo' or 'Logo' as a key, then value field convert into image upload field.
const handleCustomField = (key, value) => {
  setCustomField((pre) => ({
    ...pre,
    [key]: value,
  }));
};
const generateCustomField = () => {
  setCustomField({ key: "", value: "" });
};
const saveCustomField = () => {
  setFormFields((pre) => [
    ...pre,
    {
      ...customField,
      key: strToCamel(customField.key),
      label:
        capitalizeFirstLetter(customField.key) && strToCamel(customField.key),
    },
  ]);
  setCustomField(null);
};

//---------------------------------------------------
{
  customField && (
    <>
      <Stack
        direction="row"
        component="form"
        sx={{
          "& > :not(style)": { m: 1, width: "25ch" },
        }}
        noValidate
        autoComplete="off"
      >
        <TextField
          value={customField.key}
          onChange={(event) => handleCustomField("key", event.target.value)}
          label="Key"
        />
        <TextField
          value={customField.value}
          onChange={(event) => handleCustomField("value", event.target.value)}
          label={capitalizeFirstLetter("Value")}
        />
      </Stack>
    </>
  );
}

<Button
  variant="contained"
  size="small"
  sx={{ maxWidth: 200 }}
  endIcon={<AddIcon />}
  onClick={!customField ? generateCustomField : saveCustomField}
>
  {customField ? "Save CustomField" : "Add Custom Field"}
</Button>;

I use another state for handling this, but this code doesn't work
const [isImageUpload, setIsImageUpload] = useState(false);

const handleCustomField = (key, value) => {
  setCustomField((pre) => ({
    ...pre,
    [key]: value,
  }));
  const newKey = e.target.value;
  setKey(newKey);

  if (newKey.toLowerCase() === "logo") {
    setIsImageUpload(true);
    setValue("");
  } else {
    setIsImageUpload(false);
    setValue("");
  }
};

<label>Key:</label>
<input type="text" value={key} onChange={handleKeyChange} />
<label>Value:</label>
{isImageUpload ? (
  <input type="file" />
) : (
  <input type="text" value={value} onChange={handleValueChange} />
)}

